# Printing Bootstrap page in Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, dynamic, printing

I have an index.html I made based on this template: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/ with some minor changes (in my case, I used navbar-fixed-top and I changed .sidebar position to fixed in sb-admin-2.css)

This index is static, only changing the section content via on click event, For example

(Piece of index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>System User's Guide</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="js/respond.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

 <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0" id="top">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">System</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->  

            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                        <li class="sidebar-search">
                            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /input-group -->
                        </li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a onclick="openPage('pages/login/loginwelcome.html')" href="#">Login & Welcome</a></li>                       
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div id="content">
                        <h1 class="page-header">Home</h1>
                        <p>Welcome to our User Guide.</p>
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

    <script>
        function openPage(page) {
            $("#content").load(page);
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

(loginwelcome.html)

```
<html>    
    <h1 class="page-header">Login & Welcome</h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></li>
        <li class="active">Login & Welcome</li>
    </ol>


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a href="#links" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Content<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="links" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <a href="javascript:openPage('pages/login/login.html')">Login</a></br>
        <a href="javascript:openPage('pages/login/welcome.html')">Welcome Screen</a></br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

        <p>Test</p>
</html>
```

So, the problem is: when I try to print loginwelcome.html in Chrome or IE, it works perfectly (expanding content div width to 100%, hidding sidebar etc). But when I try to print this in Firefox, there's a huge left-margin. I tried to make some changes using bootstrap print responsive classes and modifying media @print in the css as well, but is almost like if firefox doesn't recognize changes in media @print at all. I also tried the print_printer reset (in about:config) and to change some print parameters in this section, but once you change the printer the problem is there again. 
Also, I'm hoping that there's a better way to do it or that I'm just doing something wrong in my code, cause it would be difficult to ask users to do all this "workaround".

(Sorry about any mistakes/bad explanation, its the first time I'm asking something here)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have tried something like this, but the following works for me. I'm using bootstrap, by the way.

Make sure your DOM element(s) you wish to print has the class "printable".

In your css, make sure you have:

```
@media print {
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  .printable {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -13%;
    width: 100%;
   }
  // Firefox-specific print styling:
  @supports (-moz-appearance:meterbar) {
    .printable {
      left     : -50%;
      width    : 200%;
      font-size: 0.85em;
    }   
  }
}
```

Give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this same issue (print this in Firefox, there's a huge left-margin.); the previous answer helped a lot. But, I had to set the style to container class to get everything right (Bootstrap). So, identifying the right div and setting the browser specific style should work just fine.

```
@@supports (-moz-appearance:meterbar) {
  .container {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.90em;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```